# Rotating a series of lights such that each one rotates more than the previous one

Tags: linkage

I want to rotate a series of lights that are all spaced evenly from each other with a single actuator such that when the first light rotates 1 degree, the second one will rotate 2 degrees and the third 3 degrees etc.  Does anyone know of a way to do that?

Comment: Many ways. You forgot to specify a maximum angle of rotation. What is it? What is the lamp spacing?

Comment: the last light in the line will rotate a maximum of 45 degrees.  Spacing will probably between 1.5 to 2 inches

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you want a system that can rotate up to 45 lights the corresponding number of degrees.  Wouldn't dtails like that be critical to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Belt-driven pulleys seems easiest.

[image]

Do an image search for "timing belts, pulleys and tensioners" and you should get some ideas.

Comment: The evenly spaced aspect works well in this example, but there may be limits for the larger sizes, yes? I can envision stacked pulleys to address that aspect.

Comment: @fred_dot_u, agreed, but it gets worse as you're now needing a varying ratio between adjacent lamps in a pattern like 2/1, 3/2, 4/3, 5/4, etc. "Analogue" pulleys turned to factional dimensions would be more accurate than "digital" timing pulleys which only come in integer values!